# Classified image color in Erdas Imagine

Tags: geotiff-tiff, erdas-imagine

I've a ArcMap classified image in tiff format. I want to open it in Erdas for further Accuracy assessment.

How to open the image in Erdas with same color ramp as it is given after classification?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I will do if I want to open a raster image in Erdas Imagine to export the (*.tif) image into (*.img) because the latter is an Erdas Imagine format.

There is a white paper on [how to change pixel colors and recode](http://community.hexagongeospatial.com/t5/ERDAS-IMAGINE-Q-A/Gray-scale-images-how-to-change-pixel-colors-and-recode/ta-p/2343) from HEXAGON Support and another PDF training from the same company on [Working With Raster Attributes in Erdas Imagine](http://community.hexagongeospatial.com/hmrkh95973/attachments/hmrkh95973/eTErdasImagine/6/1/Working%20with%20Raster%20Attributes%20in%20ERDAS%20IMAGINE%20Script.pdf), try to follow the instructions in these tutorials. It may give you a solution to your problem.